# How to get data from the client and not from the server or my web application?

Tags: php, proxy, http-proxy

I am trying to get user data not from my server.

I have two pages on one I have an SSL certificate and on the other I don't, I am printing data from my computer, on the SSL certificate, it prints port 443 while the one without a certificate prints port 80.

```
$PORT = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
```

The same works with the following code, in SSL it prints proxy while in the other it prints no proxy.

```
if(!gethostbyaddr(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
    || gethostbyaddr(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')) == "."
    || !getenv('HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING')
    || getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    || getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')
    || getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')
    || getenv('HTTP_VIA')
    || getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')
    || getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')
    || getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR_IP')
    || getenv('VIA')
    || getenv('X-PROXY-ID')
    || getenv('MT-PROXY-ID')
    || getenv('X-TINYPROXY')
    || getenv('PROXY-AGENT')
    || getenv('X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    || getenv('FORWARDED_FOR')
    || getenv('X_FORWARDED FORWARDED')
    || getenv('HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP')
    || getenv('CLIENT-IP')
    || getenv('CLIENT_IP')
    || getenv('FORWARDED_FOR_IP')
    || getenv('HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION')
    || getenv('PROXY_CONNECTION')
    || in_array(getenv('REMOTE_PORT'), array(8080,80,6588,8000,3128,553,554))
    || @fsockopen(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'), 80, $NUM_ERROR, $CONNECTION_TIME, 0)
    || !getenv('HTTP_CONNECTION')){
    echo 'proxy';
} else {
    echo 'no proxy';
}
```

So this is wrong, because I am getting different data, am I using the same computer?

Comment: The certificate is because it's HTTPS (secure).  HTTPS is TCP port 443 and HTTP is port 80 normally.

Comment: @AbraCadaver So I can't get the client port, in case it is modified with some VPN application.

Comment: @AbraCadaver So the function to detect the proxy does not work for the client, since it will always give positive for my SSL certificate.

Comment: I may not be understanding all that you're trying to do but  the client and if they use one, the VPN and proxy use ephemeral ports to connect to server ports, they can be 1024 – 65535.

Comment: @AbraCadaver If I understand, when I tested the code using VPN it was detected in the domain without certificate, but with the domain with certificate it stopped working.

Comment: `in_array(getenv('REMOTE_PORT'), array(8080,80,6588,8000,3128,553,554))` No, these ports are the standard/common pots that the user of the proxy will connect to, but when the proxy itself connects to your server it can use any port just like your browser, will your browser use port 80 on your computer to connect to a webserver ?

Comment: In the question you said *"in SSL it prints proxy while in the other it prints no proxy."* and in the comments you said *"when I tested the code using VPN it was detected in the domain without certificate, but with the domain with certificate it stopped working"*, **which one is correct** ?

Comment: @Accountantم In conclusion, the code is not valid then. Only on the page without certificate, it detects me when I use a VPN app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only on the page without certificate, it detects me when I use a VPN
> app

When the proxy connects to an encrypted webserver(SSL) it CAN'T modify the headers it's user sending to the final server, because all data is encrypted.

However, if the proxy is connecting to a non encrypted webserver, it will add it's own headers like `HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR`

That is why you detected the proxy on non encrypted webserver, because 1 of these 25 conditions has trapped the proxy!

**That is why detecting a proxy on an encrypted webserver is hard**, and you have to do more complicated approaches like trying to make port-scan the client IP and check if any of the common/standard proxies ports are open.

You can confirm this by doing a `var_dump($_SERVER)` in your code , and you will see that on the page with SSL, there are no proxy headers at all, and in the page without SSL I'm sure you will find one of them.

As I told you in your previous question, I suggest using an IP reputation API.